# Mix spring-integration and spring scheduler

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration

We are mixing **spring-integration** and the **scheduling capabilities from spring-boot** using:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableIntegration
@IntegrationComponentScan
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@EnableScheduling
public class MyApplication {
...
}
```

`@EnableScheduling` creates a bean named "taskScheduler" which is then used by spring-integration:

```
public abstract class IntegrationContextUtils {
  public static final String TASK_SCHEDULER_BEAN_NAME = "taskScheduler";
  ...
}
```

```
private void registerTaskScheduler() {
  if (!this.beanFactory.containsBean(IntegrationContextUtils.TASK_SCHEDULER_BEAN_NAME)) {
    ...
    this.registry.registerBeanDefinition(IntegrationContextUtils.TASK_SCHEDULER_BEAN_NAME, scheduler);
  }
}
```

Problem is, the default poolSize for spring-integration is 10 (which value is needed as we encounter starvation) while the default for spring-boot is 1 (which we also need to avoid concurrency in our scheduled processes).

**Questions**:

- Is this a normal behavior for spring-integration to share his task scheduler bean with spring-boot scheduling capabilities?
- Is there a way to specify a unique task scheduler for spring-integration, whether scheduling in boot is enabled or not?

Thanks for your answers

Comment: Hence, the ```spring.integration.taskScheduler.poolSize``` is not used if @EnableScheduling is present

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behviour and logic is correct. And expectations from the convention-on-configuration from Spring Boot perspective is also correct. Only what you miss that `@EnableScheduling` is not a Spring Boot feature, but rather Spring Framework native: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/integration.html#scheduling. Spring Boot jsut give us an extra freedom of configuration some beans on the matter. So, we just need to rely on its auto-configuration.

If auto-configuration doesn't fit your requirements, you always can provide your own configuration and override whenever it is necessary.

Looking to the `@EnableScheduling`, its `@Scheduled` hooks and appropriate `TaskSchedulingAutoConfiguration` in Spring Boot, it is not so easy to override whatever you want to make Spring Integration happy at the same time. So, we should go a bit opposite direction and really override a `Scheduler` for Spring Integration endpoints. Every single place where you use `poller`, you also need to configure a custom `Scheduler` instead of that auto-configured.

Comment: Thanks, Artem, for the quick reply.
It's crystal clear.

It seems quite odd to me that spring-integration and spring share the same thread pool by default as they clearly cover different needs, and should require different configurations.

As per our issue, I tend to prefer trying to make our processes more concurrency-proof rather than overriding the spring-boot autoconfiguration.
I will try the custom Scheduler way anyway though, just for my personal knowledge.

Again, Thanks for your answer.

Comment: It's not odd. That is how convention-on-configuration works. The same way as you auto-configure security and it is applied everywhere in your application. Or you configure a DB and `DataSource` is everywhere the same. So, just look at this `Scheduler` as a common shared resource which is really the same everywhere after auto-configuration.

Comment: Then, why is the default value for the pool size is 10 in SI and 1 in SB autoconfig?

Comment: Well, I wouldn't mix that. You don't compare apples with apples: Spring Boot is just an auto-configuration framework on top of other Spring libraries. And it is not a surprise that it has its own opinion (remember convention-on-configuration) overriding what we have by default on those libraries. For example Spring Framework doesn't expose `Scheduler` bean for `@EnableScheduling`, but Spring Boot does and so on.

Comment: I understand the opinionated way of the auto-configuration. Still, what bothers me is the fact that the threadpool is shared. To me, SI should have his own, configurable threadpool. But there are certainly a lot of side effects I don't see, this is clearly something I'm not an expert of.

Comment: One more time: look at this `Scheduler` as a `DataSource` - it is shared with all your components and so on. If you are not satisfied with it, then you inject a custom solution whenever you need.

Comment: FYI: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/pull/25109

Comment: Thanks Artem. I follow it up there on github

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to resolve this, in our case, was to override the default scheduler pool size:

```
spring.task.scheduling.pool.size=16
```

Of course the caveat is that you can not avoid concurrency of scheduled processes this way. It depends on your use case if you need that of course, but generally as soon as you can have more than one instance of your service deployed the single threaded pool wouldn't not help you anyway.

Another potential issue is that the scheduler still might hog all threads and block your integration flows, or vice versa. If this is a real issue in your use case, you must configure separate thread pools as Artem suggested.